# Is there a way to run my existing React Native project on Snack locally?

Tags: react-native, expo

I've got a React Native project that was recently upgraded to RN 0.56.

This is fine for the Mac users, but [0.56 is broken on Windows](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/8w8qsd/facebook_just_released_reactnative_056_which_is/).

Since it's specifically the Metro bundler that seems to be the issue, I was wondering whether there was any way to run my project locally in something like Snack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the age of this question and the lack of responses, I'm inferring that the answer is "no".

For any future explorers, it might be helpful to know that I searched pretty exhaustively for a way to make this work, without success.

In the end, RN 0.57 fixed Windows support, so this became a non-issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

You can import a public git repository or javascript files. You can also export a project. All the import/export options are accessible from the project menu (as shown in the image below): 
[image]